# How to set the header of a TabItem when using ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, xaml

Its useful to bind a collection of usercontrols to the ItemsSource property of a TabControl.

However, once you go this path it seems hard to set the header of each tabitem from code.
I could do it from xaml *but I need to do it from code*.

So what I'm looking for is something along the lines of

```
TabControl tabControl = new TabControl();

tabControl.ItemsSource = collectionOfUserControls;

tabControl.HeaderPath = "Title" // this property is not available
```

**EDIT**

This is how to one can do it if manualy adding to the collection. The questions is how to set the header when using the ItemsSource property.

```
        var vragenlijsten = new UserControl[]
                                {
                                    new UC1() ,
                                    new UC2(), 
                                };


        TabControl tabControl = new TabControl();

        foreach (var vragenlijst in vragenlijsten)
        {
            var tabItem = new TabItem();
            tabItem.Content = vragenlijst;
            tabItem.Header = vragenlijst.GetType();
            tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem);
        }
```

Comment: Why exaclty do you need to do that from code?. There is a HeaderTemplate too..

Comment: I like to know how to do it in code :) If it's not doable/practical  thats knowledge as well

Comment: Nothing is practical when you bring a "traditional" mindset and try to use it in WPF. In fact, I see a TabControl as an IEnumerable of ViewModels, which are then rendered on screen with their respective views. That's what the WPF mindset is about.

Answer (score 0):

If you **must** do it in code, you'd need to retrieve the `TabItem`s and set the header for each of them. Something like this:

```
(tabControl.Items[0] as TabItem).Header = "Title";
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable but have you tried it? If you use ItemsSource to bind you will find that cast an item of the Items collection is not a TabItem.

Comment: I have tried it. My answer assumes that your `collectionOfUserControls` is a collection of `TabItem`s. If you have more controls that are not TabItems (although I don't know why you would) you could just add a check before, like: `if(tabControl.Items[0] is TabItem)`.